# "Dynamic route" with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create a route which can change while the program is running.
Example : `app.get('/',function(req,res){/*Something here*/};` This is a normal route.
I want to replace the `'/'` with a variable which can be replaced with a random number. After that I'll create a qrcode with a nodejs module and the user who scans this qrcode will confirm a kind of transaction.

If you understand my idea and you have a solution, I'll take it.

Comment: Use [parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param).

Comment: Yeah ofc, but the url in the qrcode must be unique and random.

Comment: That's what params are for. Also please show some effort (what you've tried so far and didn't work for you etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Louy said, use [`parameters`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param):

```
var getQRCode = require('./yourQRCodeModule');

app.param('qrcode', function(req, res, next, qrcode) {
  // qrcode will be "1234" if your request path was "/1234"
  console.log('checking qrcode: %s', qrcode);

  // get the qrcode from some asynchronous function
  getQRCode(qrcode, function callback(err, qrcode) {
    // if this number was not a valid dynamic path, return an error from your module

    console.log('qrcode was %s', (!err && qrcode) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');

    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else if (qrcode) {
      req.qrcode = qrcode; // object from your module
      next();
    } else {
      next(new Error('failed to load QR code'));
    }
  });
});

app.get('/:qrcode', function (req, res) {
  // req.qrcode will be the object from your module
  // if the number was invalid, this will never be called
});
```

What I'm trying to point out is that you're thinking of this scenario differently than how express approaches the problem. You want a one-time route with a specific qrcode, but these kind of routes don't exist in express. So here's what I understand your ideal solution to look like:

1. server creates "azjzso1291084JKioaio1" for a qrcode
2. you register something like `app.getOnce("azjzso1291084JKioaio1", function(req, res){...})`
3. first time the request gets called, it's removed from your express router

Here's what I'm suggesting:

1. server creates "azjzso1291084JKioaio1" for a qrcode
2. your module stores this qrcode either in a database or in memory, **within your module**, e.g. `var qrcodes = {}; qrcodes["azjzso1291084JKioaio1"] = {some: 'object'};`
3. your `app.param` asynchronous function based on the example given in step 2 could look like this:

```
// yourQRCodeModule.js
var qrcodes = {};

qrcodes["azjzso1291084JKioaio1"] = {some: 'object'};

module.exports = function getQRCode(qrcode, callback) {
  if (qrcodes[qrcode]) {
    var obj = qrcodes[qrcode]; // copy object
    delete qrcodes[qrcode]; // remove from memory here
    callback(null, obj);
  } else {
    // invalid path
    callback(new Error('invalid QR code'), null);
  }
};
```

Now notice if you request `/azjzso1291084JKioaio1` twice, the second time fails. This is how you intend it to work, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: The problem is not to create the qrcode. The server must generate a random variable like "azjzso1291084JKioaio1" the qrcode redirect to localhost/azjzso1291084JKioaio1. I need to "create" a route when the user click on a link. I do'nt know if i'm understandable ....

Comment: @Arwinne1 yes I understand your problem. But express does not work this way. The way you should be doing this is creating the random variable in your module, then when someone requests a path with the pattern that you're expecting, you use your module to check the temporary random variable, then allow the request to go through.

Comment: I understand a little x) like i said i'm not rambo. I have no idea how to do this. I had search on the web with no succes !

Comment: @Arwinne1 I added more detail about how my approach works

Comment: I'll try this later. Thanks for all, you help a noobie baguette, respect !